# Regex to check for at least 8 digits and exactly 2 characters

Tags: regex

I'd like to make an regular expression that check in a string that match at least 8 digits and exactly 2 characters in uppercase. the letters and decimals can be anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: This is not achivable by regex I believe.

Comment: If lookarounds are supported you can assert 8 or more digits and match 2 times A-Z `^(?=(?:[^\r\n0-9]*[0-9]){8})[^A-Z\r\n]*[A-Z][^A-Z\r\n]*[A-Z\r\n][^A-Z\r\n]*$` https://regex101.com/r/xWao6f/1

Comment: @Mahmoud Can you update the question with the pattern you have tried and an example of what should and should not match?

Comment: @Eraklon It is most definitely achievable by many regex engines (not all). That being said, regex is probably not the most efficient or straight-forward tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks a lot this one work perfectly 
^(?=[A-Z0-9]{10})\d*[A-Z]\d*[A-Z]\d*$

Comment: @Mahmoud - Don't forget to "accept" the correct answer (looks like you used JvdV's answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would [this](https://regex101.com/r/oOCSE5/11) work:

```
^(?=[A-Z0-9]{10,})\d*[A-Z]\d*[A-Z]\d*$
```

- `^` - Match start of string
- `(?=[A-Z0-9]{10,})` - A positive LookAhead to match at least 10 chars from `[A-Z0-9]` only
- `\d*[A-Z]\d*[A-Z]\d*` - Two chars in the range `[A-Z]` surrounded by zero or more digits
- `$` - Match end of string

Alternatively, create another capture group:

```
^(?=[A-Z0-9]{10,})(\d*[A-Z]){2}\d*$
```

Now you got a little bit more flexibility to tell the pattern you need an x-amount of upper case letters > `{x}`

Comment: ^(?=[A-Z0-9]{10})\d*[A-Z]\d*[A-Z]\d*$