# Match text with 4 to 5 CAPITAL ALPAHABETS along with minimum 1 or maximum 2 digit number

Tags: python, regex

**Requirement:**

```
4 to 5 CAPITAL ALPAHABETS along with minimum 1 or maximum 2 digit number
```

I have created a REGEX which matches string with CAPITAL ALPHABETS which has more than 1 digit but I want to match Text which has only 1 or 2 digits.

```
\b(?=.*\d){1,2}(?=.*[A-Z])[A-Z\d]{4,5}\b
```

**Match Cases:**

Allow

```
8HB8
H8ER
D5KC2
```

Disallow

```
8HB88
HEER
D54C2
```

Edit 1:

I should be able to match WORDs of that format with in sentence also not alone as word.

Allow:

```
This is a valid 9CB8 code
This is another valid H1CS code
```

Comment: can you tell me which output you want?

Comment: @MuhammadNuman I want to create a regex which matches the given matching codition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to assert 4-5 chars `[A-Z0-9]`.

Then match at least 1 digit 0-9 between optional chars `[A-Z]` and optionally match a second digit.

```
^(?=[A-Z0-9]{4,5}$)[A-Z]*[0-9][A-Z]*(?:[0-9][A-Z]*)?$
```

*In parts*

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[A-Z0-9]{4,5}$)` Assert 4-5 chars A-Z0-9
- `[A-Z]*[0-9][A-Z]*` Match a digit between optional chars A-Z
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[0-9][A-Z]*` match a digit 0-9
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PdzWQz/1)

Comment: This also matches H8A8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Comment: @The6thSense I forgot the anchor `$` https://regex101.com/r/PdzWQz/1 I have updated the answer.

Comment: Nice explaination as usual.

Comment: Hi just one small problem this works with WORD and not with sentence i.e.) "This is a code 8HB8 and it works" i want to match 8HB8. Sorry if my question was not correct editing it.

Comment: @The6thSense Try it like this using a word boundary`\b(?=[A-Z0-9]{4,5}\b)[A-Z]*[0-9][A-Z]*(?:[0-9][A-Z]*)?\b`  https://regex101.com/r/dbebqy/1

Answer (score 2):

So maybe you could use:

```
^(?=[A-Z0-9]{4,5}$)(?:\D*\d\D*){1,2}$
```

I based my answer on the same principle as I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60228056/9758194).

- `^` - Start of string ancor
- `(?=[A-Z0-9]{4,5}$)` - A positive lookahead for a minimum of 4 and a maximum of 5 characters in the range of [A-Z0-9] before the end of string ancor, $.
- `(?:\D*\d\D*)` - A non-capture group where we have a combination of: zero or more non-digits followed by a digit and again zero or more non-digits.
- `{1,2}` - Allow the previous non-capture group to occur a minimum of 1 and a maximum of two times (to make sure there are only 1 or 2 digits.
- `$` - End of string ancor.

See the online demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/y0Jg6O/3) and below is a visualization of the pattern from left to right:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Could you please explain the regex as well

Comment: @The6thSense, does the update make things clear? I changed the `[A-Z]` character classes to `\D` - A non-digit character.

Comment: I think it can even be one more character shorter using `^(?=.{4,5}$)(?:[A-Z]*\d[A-Z]*){1,2}$` =) but that soo minor =) @The6thSense

Comment: Hi just one small problem this works with WORD and not with sentence i.e.) "This is a code 8HB8 and it works" i want to match 8HB8. Sorry if my question was not correct editing it.